# Printing out only one result in batch mode with Prolog

Tags: prolog

In Prolog, I can bring up the REPL to test Prolog code interactively (interactive mode), and I also can write down the code in a file to be executed from command line (batch mode).

In interactive mode, I use `setof` function to get all the results.

```
?- [likes].
?- setof(X, likes(sam, X), L).
L = [chips, chop_suey, chow_mein, dahl, kurma, pizza, spaghetti, sweet_and_sour, tandoori].
```

I can keep asking the results from `?- likes(sam, X)`, 
I also can use `once` function to get only one result.

```
?- once(likes(sam,X)).
X = dahl.
```

For I can use the same setof function to get the results printed out in batch mode.

```
:- initialization main.

main :- 
    [likes],
    setof(X, likes(sam, X), L),
    write(L),
    halt.
```

Then, how can I get and print out the result of `once(likes(sam,X))`?
I tried to use `L2 = once(likes(sam, X)` to print out the result in `L2`, but I got errors.

In general, how to get the results that of the interactive mode?
For example, how to print out the results (true or false value) of `?- likes(sam, dahl)` in batch mode?

Comment: Your first question, use: `once(likes(sam,X)), write(X), nl`. Your second question, use: `( likes(sam, dahl) -> write('true') ; write('false') ), nl`. Is that what you're after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write out the result of `once(likes(sam,X))`:

```
once(likes(sam, X)),
write(X), ...
```

If you want to output false if no `X` is found, then:

```
(   once(likes(sam, X))
->  write(X)
;   write('Nobody likes sam')
), ...
```

`L2 = once(likes(sam, X))` would fail because Prolog predicates are not functions that return values. This expression just unifies `L2` with the term `once(likes(sam, X))`.

If you want to write out whether a ground query, such as `likes(sam, dahl)` succeeds or fails:

```
(   likes(sam, dahl)
->  write('true')
;   write('false')
), ...
```